# Should I explicit specify default value for SELECT even if it is the first one

Tags: html, forms, html-select

In all browsers that I know of, the first option is selected pr default in the below HTML:

```
<select>
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</select>
```

But can I count on this behavior? Or would it be better practice to explicit specify default value even when it is the first option, ie would it be safer to go:

> ```
> <select>
>   <option selected>foo</option>
>   <option>bar</option>
> </select>
> ```

Comment: One case might be when you press the back button and your browser uses the old form values. But then, `selected` probably wouldn't take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HTML(5) specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-selected) doesn't say that the default selected option should be the first one if no `selected` attribute is present.

> The selectedness of an option element is a boolean state, initially false. Except where otherwise specified, when the element is created, its selectedness must be set to true if the element has a selected attribute. Whenever an option element's selected attribute is added, its selectedness must be set to true.

It [does however say](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-select-selectedindex) that if no `selected` value is present then the default should be to return a selectedness value of -1.

> The selectedIndex IDL attribute, on getting, must return the index of the first option element in the list of options in tree order that has its selectedness set to true, if any. **If there isn't one, then it must return −1.**

I guess you therefore *shouldn't* assume that the first option will always be selected as default.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it matters. It's only if you do not have your default value at the top. The "selected" is if you want to change the default option. If you don't have it on the top.

Like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: do you know if this is a documented behavior of HTML

Comment: Hmm, no sorry. But I think it's a function so you don't need to rearrange the code all the time. You can read a little bit more here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Answer (score 0):

On first render (or perhaps when the `<select>` element is created), the first `<option>` is implicitly selected: [`selectedIndex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-select-selectedindex) returns **0**, and [`selected`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-option-selected) (of first option) returns **true**.

But if you change the options with JavaScript, for example remove all options and add new ones, then `selectedIndex` returns **-1**, and `selected` (of first option) returns **false**.

All the above assumes, of course, that the [`selected="selected"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-selected) attribute is never used.

So, if you are dynamically adding options, and want to make use the first is initially selected, then you **must** use the selected attribute.